# Change IIS Default Physical Path

Tags: windows-server-2008, iis

I am new to Windows 2008 Server and IIS 7. I just installed IIS on the box. By default, the physical path for default web site is pointed to %SystemDrive%\inetpub\wwwroot. It is at C: drive.

I prefer to change this default path to D: drive. I found that this setting is available at default web site's Advanced settings. I am not sure if there is anything else I have to do to make this change?

Answer (score 0):

The only other change you need to do is to ensure that the account under which IIS runs is authorized to access the new directory. Under my Vista+IIS7, this account name is IIS_IUSERS. Make sure that you do not grant too many rights on this directory. It should probably be read-only for this account.